# Automatically authenticate gspread in Collab

Tags: python, gspread

I currently have a script which reads a Google Sheet URL, and converts to a dataframe. To access this file, I need to authenticate each time I run the script. Is there an alternative which means I only have to do this once?

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
wb = gc.open_by_url('...')
sheet = wb.worksheet('Sheet1')
data = sheet.get_all_values()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks!